# Transitioning old bike to be indoor and stationary

Tags: rear-wheel, wheel-building, stationary-bike

I'm turning my mom's old bike into a stationary one, I don't know much about bikes and have a few questions.

Do I need a quick release skewer for the back wheel?

Will something break if I don't have a QR?

If replacement is necessary what do I need to do?   I know less about tools than I do about bikes so I have no clue what I need for this. I tried all my random garage wrenches.

Also does anyone have recommendations for the front wheel stands? I have the one the [spinner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MB8DR8Q) came with but it's kind of garbage.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site    "I have the one the spinner came with"   Could you expand on what that is ?  What's a spinner in this case?   A photo might help.

Comment: A stationary bike stand, I got this one https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MB8DR8Q?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bike appears to have a solid axle with acorn-style wheel nuts on the rear.

The trainer you've linked seems to come with its own QR skewer, which is intended to fit into the trainer's retention system properly.

If you can install the trainer to the existing wheel nuts in a firm and secure way, then you're good to ride as-is.

However if there's excessive slop or a poor fit, then the bike will move around in the trainer.  This will slowly damage things over time, and worst case the bike could pop out of the trainer and you'll probably fall over.

---

If you want to use the QR on your bike, then you'll need to change the axle to a hollow one.  That's not hard but its certainly fiddly.

It wouldn't be too expensive to take just the rear wheel to a bike shop and request they fit a kit like this:

[image]

This will swap out the solid axle you have for a slightly shorter hollow axle, that you can put the QR skewer though.

---

Lastly, the front wheel riser block is just to make your bike level while its on the trainer.  You can use old phone books or a concrete block or anything you like.  Can even remove the front wheel and secure the fork dropouts to a convenient-height shelf, or build some bolts into a TV stand that you can watch while riding.

Do be aware the bike is an extra couple-inches off the ground, so getting on and off can cause a mis-step.  You might put a stepping stone/apple box there to help with mounting and dismounting.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: @guest56439812 yeah the trick with these things is not to lean while riding.  If you push the bike around, or pedal out-of-the-saddle then they can get quite unstable.